# Rails chat update in real-time (AJAX or WebSokets)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Good day. I am really new with Rails and I am trying to find the way how to auto-update the message list in chat window.

I'll describe what I got:

1. I have an  `<input type="text">` which is saved to the mysql db each time I press **Send** button.
2. Each time I send a message the page refreshes itself and I recieve the last 5 ones(including the one which I send).

What I want to do is:
while 2 people are typing/sending their messages both will got auto-update from db without refreshing the page or pressing **Send** button. If user_1 sends then user_2 recieves it automatically.

I need some how to refresh this variables:

```
 <%=@date[i][1]%>

 <%=@message[i]%>
```

I have read about AJAX long poll and WebSockets, but I understand nothing.

main.html.erb:

```
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 10%">Time</th>
      <th style="width: 90%">Message</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% for i in 0..4 %>
        <tr>
          <td ><div class="well well-sm"><%=@date[i][1]%></div></td>
          <td ><div class="well well-sm"><%=@message[i]%></div></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Controller:

```
def main
    if(session[:isLogin]!=true)
      redirect_to :controller => 'auth', :action => 'index'
    end

      @mess_count = 5
      @output = Chat.last(@mess_count)
      @message = []
      @date = []

    for i in 0..@mess_count-1
      @date[i] = @output[i][:date].to_s.split(' ')
      @message[i] = @output[i][:message]
    end
```

P.S. I know that my code sucks, but I just need the general idea of live-time chat message update. Thank you.

Comment: AJAX is unreliable for this type of application. Try this instead:  http://websocket-rails.github.io/

Comment: @Jason, websocket-rails hadn't been updated since Jun 5, 2014... I doubt it's still maintained. Have a look at the [Plezi framework](http://www.plezi.io/). It's great for real-time (websockets) applications and it's easy to use it inside a Rails application. (I'm biased, being the author).

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm actually about to start a WebSocket project in Rails very soon. You probably just saved me a bunch of trouble.

Comment: thank you. trying to write my own project.

Answer (score 1):

[ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/actioncable) is a Websockets framework for developing real time apps with Rails. Its developed by the Rails core team and rumor has it will be included in Rails 5.

You can give it a whirl already - but you should be prepared to do quite a bit of reading - websockets can be pretty daunting and requires a pretty good grasp of javascript and client / server interaction.